# How to cancel current Http Request to controller in spring

Tags: jquery, spring, web, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I have a requirement of canceling the current http request to controller sent by the web browser on clicking of any submit button.
Means If I click on the submit button then I should have a cancel option available on the screen so that I can cancel that request and can send the other request.

I need the suggestion on this as What will be the best approach to implement this scenario and whether it's feasible or not.

Note: If I missed to tagged the right guy please suggest.

Comment: I think you don't wanna cancel a http request, but a business logic request, if it is the case, you can have the request saved in DB with status, and cancel it by changing its status

Comment: Thanks for your response
No @Jaiwo99 I want to cancel the http request only Because some time we get response very late So I want to give option to user to cancel the old request and resend the new request

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set a timeout for your request.

If you are making the request with ajax, you can set the timeout in the ajax invocation with "timeout" attribute. (Offical documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

If you made the request with a web browser, you have to configure a timeout in your application's backend, or you can cancel the request when you want touching the key "ESC".